# How do I reshape an image to NxNx3 blocks and perform operations on their channels separately

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to get a better understanding of numpy reshaping and transpose operations so that I can perform tasks on each local area of a color image (as opposed to the image as a whole). I can do these by creating slices and looping over slices, but I would prefer not having to create python loops. I have come up with some examples that should help me understand the parts that I have been having trouble with. I ordered them from easiest to most difficult. The last one is ultimately the one that I want to solve.

```
img = np.random.randint(low=0, high=256, size=(6,6,3), dtype=np.uint8)

img_mean = np.mean(img) #mean of the whole image, one value.
channel_means = np.mean(img, axis=(0,1)) #mean of each channel, three values.

binarized_img = np.where(img > img_mean, np.uint8(255), np.uint8(0)) #all values changed to either 0 or 255. Shape of image remains 5,5,3.
binarized_channels = #I would like to be able to do the same as above, but by using a different mean for each channel and without using python loops.

three_by_three_block_means = #I want to reshape the array into four 3x3x3 blocks and get each block's mean (should be 4 different means).
three_by_three_block_channel_means = #Same as above, but this time I want the mean of each channel of each block (should be 12 different means).
#I also want to be able to change the block's size arbitrarily, i.e. from 3x3x3 blocks to 2x2x3 blocks when needed.

binarized_blocks = #same as binarized_img, but done separately for each block based on their means instead of the mean of the whole image.
binarized_block_channels = #same as binarized_blocks, but done separately for each channel in each block.
```

If someone could show me how to complete these examples using only numpy (no python loops), I could learn from them and use them to accomplish the (similar) tasks that I frequently have trouble with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to your problem are *Strided Convolutions*, use [`scipy.signal.convolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html) to compute the block means.

```py
from scipy import signal

img = np.random.randint(low=0, high=256, size=(6,6,3), dtype=np.uint8)

img_mean = np.mean(img) #mean of the whole image, one value.
channel_means = np.mean(img, axis=(0,1)) #mean of each channel, three values.

binarized_img = np.where(img > img_mean, np.uint8(255), np.uint8(0)) #all values changed to either 0 or 255. Shape of image remains 5,5,3.
```

> I would like to be able to do the same as above, but by using a
> different mean for each channel and without using python loops.

```py
binarized_channels = np.where(img > channels_mean, np.uint8(0),np.uint8(255))
```

> I want to reshape the array into four 3x3x3 blocks and get each
> block's mean (should be 4 different means).

Define a mean kernel (all ones divided by the sum of the kernel) of arbitrary shape, and perform a valid convolution of the image. Since `scipy` does not offer a stride argument we have to do this manually with `[::s,::s]`.

```py
s = 3
kernel = np.ones((s,s,s))/s**3
three_by_three_block_means = signal.convolve(img, kernel, 'valid')[::s,::s] # shape: (2, 2, 1)
```

> Same as above, but this time I want the mean of each channel of each
> block (should be 12 different means).

```py
kernel = np.ones(s,s,1)/s**2
three_by_three_block_channel_means = np.concolve(img, kernel, 'valid')[::s,::s] # shape: (2, 2, 3)
```

> I also want to be able to change the block's size arbitrarily, i.e.
> from 3x3x3 blocks to 2x2x3 blocks when needed.

Simply change the size of the kernel.

> Same as `binarized_img`, but done separately for each block based on
> their means instead of the mean of the whole image.

```py
binarized_blocks = np.where(three_by_three_block_means > img_mean,np.uint8(0),np.uint8(255))
```

> Same as `binarized_blocks`, but done separately for each channel in each
> block.

```py
binarized_block_channels = np.where(three_by_three_block_channel_means > channel_means, np.uint8(0), np.uint8(255))
```

Hope that solves your problem. Let me know if something is unclear.